# the data is sometimes shown and sometimes not shown in the element li

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I am trying to fetch data from an ASP.Net WebMethod and load it into `li` elements. The WebMethod is running smoothly. However, sometimes the data does not appear in the `li`. What is the reason for this? My sample codes are as follows:

```js
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {
  Ust_Menuyu_Getir();
});

function Ust_Menuyu_Getir() {
  var Domain = window.location.hostname;
  var MenuTuru = 1;
  var veriler = {
    Domainim: Domain,
    MenuTurum: MenuTuru
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Anasayfa.aspx/MenuleriGetir",
    data: JSON.stringify(veriler),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      var HizmetIslemleri = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
      $.each(data.d, function(i, v) {
        $("#ustmenum").append('<li><a href="' + v.MenuURL + '">' + v.MenuMetni + '</a></li>');
        $("#tabanmenum").append('<li><a href="' + v.MenuURL + '">' + v.MenuMetni + '</a></li>');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Check the console for errors whenever it 'doesn't work'. Please let us know what it says

Comment: Hello.
console does not show any errors. Method works fine. But the data coming from the method sometimes does not appear in the element li sometimes. When it does not appear, it becomes visible when I refresh the page. So the menu is not stable